# Recognize binary architecture

Tags: ida, binary-analysis, arm, binwalk

I have binary that run on Arm Thumb cpu, in embedded devive that **not running Linux**.

When I tried to run `bimwalk` or `file` ,and even open it with Ida ,but they didn't find out that this binary run on Arm processor.

I succeed open it with Ida only when I look on the Cpu board and find out this is Arm.

Is there any tool(without look on Cpu board)  that can find out know which processor is for to binary?

Answer (score 1):

Binwalk has this feature but you need to enable it explicitly:

> -A, --opcodes
>
> Scan target file(s) for common executable opcode signatures

A project which explicitly tries to determine an architecture of a given binary is [`cpu_rec` from Airbus](https://github.com/airbus-seclab/cpu_rec).

Please note that both solutions can only handle a small set of processors: binwalk has a short list of hardcoded opcode sequences and cpu_rec relies on a small corpus of training files. If your binary uses unusual instructions or processor it might be not recognized.

Comment: What do you mean unusual instructions? In Arm for example there are list of instruction that can be used.    Which one of those tools do you recommend?

Comment: [ISAdetect](https://github.com/kairis/isadetect) is far superior to cpu_rec. Paper: [Towards usable automated detection of CPU architecture and endianness for arbitrary binary files and object code sequences](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.05459)

Comment: @julian feel free to add your own answer with detailed description and maybe some comparisons